# Dynamically Creating a <div> to Place Javascript Slideshow in

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to place a div within a long set of javascript that runs alongside hundreds of pages. This div needs to be an empty  that a javascript slideshow will get placed into.
The javascript controling the slideshow are also dynamically loaded onto the page from one singular javascript. Because of this, I don't know if I need to load the div at the top of the script, to avoid a conflict, and then have document.write or something insert the div. I'm just now learning javascript.

Any help is much appreciated:

Here's the code I'm working with and what I tried with theplacement of fadeshow1:

```
writeButton("","/hardware-accessories.html","p_Hardware",206,20,"Hardware and Accessories","",0);

document.write("<td><img src=\""+loc+"Separator03"+gtype+"\" alt=\"\" width=\"206\" height=\"96\"></td>");

//what Im trying to add.
var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
var divIdName = 'fadeshow1';
newdiv.setAttribute('fadeshow1',divIdName);
document.body.appendChild(newdiv); 

writeButton("","/uploads.aspx","upload",206,105,"","",0);
writeButton("","","inf00",206,38,"","",0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

---

You get the same result with

```
document.write('<div fadeshow1="fadeshow1"></div>');
```

---

Otherwise you can put your code in a function

```
function append_div() {
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
   var divIdName = 'fadeshow1';
   newdiv.setAttribute('fadeshow1',divIdName);
   document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

and call it where you want the div appears `append_div();`
Just pay attention to declare the function BEFORE to call it.

Comment: I've tried using both those methods, and the problem is an alert comes up from the browser that says "Error"DIV with ID "fadeshow1" not found on page.  The other javascripts that load my slideshow on the pages load into that empty fadeshow1 DIV, so would I need to preload the div somehow onto the page? Thanks for your help!

Comment: No need to "preload". Just create the DIV Element, assign it the ID, append it to the DOM. Then call the slideshow controler.
In your code the problem could be the way ID is assigned: put `newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);` at third line.
@Jamund you're right, document.write doesn't create a node in DOM. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Many many people have solved this problem before. I would start by looking at their solutions. `document.write` is almost never the current way to solve problems as @Salvador has pointed out.

- http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
- http://slidesjs.com/

Most of these pre-existing solutions are *very* easy to use and make work with a variety of situations. It's not a bad question, it's just that the way you've tried to solve it is very complicated. You're going to have to learn a little bit of JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to make this happen. You may even need to learn the very basics of jQuery. Let me tell you whatever investment you make in learning these technologies is well worth it.

Here's a great jQuery tutorial that may help you get started:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/

Best of luck and remember to update people like @Salvador that help you!